# Intent for app storage settings

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to find out if there's an intent for the app-specific storage screen as seen below in the picture.

I tried the following code but it only opened the App Info screen:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:" + myPackage);
intent =.setData(packageURI);
startActivity(intent);
```

[image]

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible.

You can not go further than the app settings, using the Intent you posted. What you could do is explain the user how to clear the data before firing  the Intent though.

Answer (score 1):

### intent for open Internal storage settings

```
Intent intent  = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_INTERNAL_STORAGE_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Comment: I believe you did not understand the OP problem, the ACTION_INTERNAL_STORAGE_SETTINGS would open up the storage settings not the application (or package) storage settings.